Weightpainting workflow for clothes
I'm working on the production for a historical video and some debate came up in the team.
Mostly regarding the skinning/weight painting of the clothing items.
Debate might be a big word, so far no blood no lions and no arenas (yes it is about Romans) but still.
Having my opinions on the subject I'm bringing it to the ultimate judge, the Internet.

If you were to weight-paint this toga, how would you go about it? More especially the skirt part of it. If it can help, it will be rigged to an Unreal MetaHuman skeleton/template (some keen-eyed viewers might have recognised it)

Debating around which way is the best is IMHO pointless as it mostly depends on the context and you are the best person for that. Plus opinion-based topics are out of topic on this Q&A website. But we can give you a sample of different ways to approach things so that you have a wider idea of the options available to you!
I'd say there are two axes to think about it: How deep in realism you want to go and how much you can do with the rig.
If you need to go deep in realism, i'd question the need to even bother rigging the clothes at all, cloth simulations sound more appropriate (though I am no expert in that subject in Blender). Or alternatively, if you are going to use this in Unreal Engine (or another game engine), cloth simulation in the Game Engine might just be faster / more cost/time effective no matter the aimed realism).
Otherwise, if you are able to customize the rig to take the clothing into account, I would have bones specifically made for the clothes: at least some parts of the belt, and the hanging parts (skirts, but also why not some of the slack from the arm openings). Little bones here and there, similar to the tweak bones you have in Rigify's head module. Each bone controls a small area of mesh nearby. And on top of that, have controllers parent of multiple tweak bones, and for the case of the skirt: have these upper-level controllers be an FK chain from waist to knees, perhaps even an intermediate controller for each leg part too.

This would give you a detailed-enough solution that can be both hand animated and somewhat automated: you can for example have the cloth-leg controllers driven by the actual legs, have the shoulder bones drive the cloth controllers around them, have some form of physical simulations do all the heavy lifting for you.
For more info about how these kinds of setups are done in Blender, Pierrick Picault did a few videos about them:

Skirt and dress Rigging in Blender - YouTube
Hand keyed cloth animation in Blender - YouTube
Dynamic cloth rigging and animation in Blender - YouTube
Create and transfer cloth simulation to an animated character rig in Blender - YouTube

If you can't modify the biped rig, then basically you don't have many options: the weights of the clothes basically need to "align" to the body's weights underneath. For the skirt, you will not escape bad deformation between the legs (good thing it stays above the knee, that would be another level of troubles). The best fix for that would be a corrective shapekey driven by the legs bones angles.
